# Handler for bidirectional unit conversion form

Tags: javascript, converting, form, event-handling

Building a [form](http://brinsterinc.com/ovn/lbskilos.html) where values can be entered in either pounds or kilos.

Script is...

```
function onlyNumber(fld) {
     if(fld.value.match(/[^0-9.]/)) {
     fld.value=fld.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');
     }
}
function convertUnit(sense, value) {
    retValue = 0;
    if (isNaN (value)) { alert ('Non-numeric value');  return 0; }
    value = parseFloat (value);
    var factor = 0.4536;
    if (sense == 'kg2lb') {
         retValue = value/factor;
         retValue = Math.round(retValue);
    }
    else if (sense == 'lb2kg') {
         retValue = value*factor;
         retValue = Math.round(retValue);
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

Works fine but I have to repeat this on every input:

```
onblur="this.form.kg_va.value=convertUnit('lb2kg',this.value);"     
onkeyup="onlyNumber(this);" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }"
```

Is there some way to simplify the `onblur` code ?

For example, is there a way to have the function focus on the same var pairs? The var pair being `lb_FOOBAR` and `kg_FOOBAR`.

And what about the input functions that are exactly the same?

```
onkeyup="onlyNumber(this);" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }"
```

Any way to avoid having to repeat them for each input? Form will have 12 fields.

Comment: Your function `onlyNumber` assumes a `.` for decimal notation. This is not true for most of the world. You could add some logic to that function to do a better guess. [Some info](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inlining the script, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead. To retrieve the elements, you'd need something like [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to return an array-like structure of elements. You loop through them, and attach a listener each.

```
var formInputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.form-input'));
formInputs.forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener('blur', function(){
    // blur code
  });
  element.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    // blur code
  });
});
```

The `Array.prototype.slice.call` is to convert the array-like structure returned by `querySelectorAll` into a real array. That's so I can use `forEach`. But a regular `for` loop will do, since a NodeList (the array-like structure) has a length property.

Now instead of `alert` and `return`, why not throw an error instead?

```
if(isNaN(value)) throw new Error('Non-numeric value');
```

Also, instead of putting all your conversions in a single function and sending a "sense", why not create a function for each kind of conversion? It's more verbose, but you don't have to pile up everything in one function.

Comment: I'd suggest using `element.addEventListener('input' fn);` instead of `keyup`, as this will break when a user pastes input

Comment: I disagree on throwing the error, I don't think most users will look in their console to see why nothing happens.